# launchFragmentInContainer unable to resolve Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing, androidx

While writing a simple test which uses `launchFragmentInContainer`, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.myapp.appname.debug/androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity (has extras) }
```

The basic test class is:

```
class OneFragmentTest {

    @Test
    fun testOneFragmentState_checkTitleText() {
        val args = Bundle().apply {
            putString("dummyKey", "dummyValue")
        }
        launchFragmentInContainer<OneFragment>(args)

        onView(withId(R.id.tv_title)).check(matches(withText("title here")))
    }
}
```

I have tried to update `AndroidManifest.xml` with the following:

```xml
<instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.myapp.appname" />
```

but it seems that the tag `instrumentation` is valid but the values are written in red, so I assume something is wrong with the `targetPackage` and `name`.

How can I get rid of this error and run a simple test on OneFragment using `launchFragmentInContainer`?

Comment: Why did you need the `<instrumentation>` tag in AndroidManifest?  Google never said to use it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The error was related to the way I did import the dependencies on Gradle.

Before:

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-beta01")
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-beta01")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.2.0")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.2.0")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.2.0")
```

After:

```
debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-beta01")
debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-beta01")
debugImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.2.0")
debugImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.2.0")
debugImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.2.0")
```

Changed from `androidTestImplementation` to `debugImplementation` and it solved the issue. Compiling and running, and green test as result.

Comment: It's good that you found solution, but https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project how come it's working for them?

Comment: you can use debugImplementation so it doesn't get built in with your release builds

Comment: set `debugImplementation` for `fragment-testing` should be enough, rest test dependencies can stay as `androidTestImplementation

Comment: why do we need to change ```debugImplementation``` ?

Comment: Setting DebugImplementation just fo fragment-testing is OK (as mentioned in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing#configure))

Comment: That makes no sense.  All Espresso tests go in `androidTestImplementation`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yeah it sounds weird, but Google itself mentioned exactly the same workaround here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-test-doubles#7 see on top in Step1. Reason is, that `androidx.fragment` dependency is buggy and as it is usual for Google, it took them more than 2 years to fix. Reported bug from 2020 here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128612536A And FINALLY, it looks like it is gonna be fixed in just few days with freshly released ` 1.6.0-alpha04` so let's celebrate :))

Answer (score 12):

Try to configure this way

```
debugImplementation('androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0') {
        // exclude androidx.test:core while fragment_testing depends on 1.1.0
        exclude group: 'androidx.test', module: 'core'
    }
```

Comment: After changing androidTestImplementation to debugImplementation I got errors in my manifest that I don't have 'exported' field and it is needed in android 12 and above which I had it in my manifest and it was keep complaining, but this answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

it works for me

```
def fragmentx_version = "1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragmentx_version"
debugImplementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragmentx_version"){
     exclude group: 'androidx.test', module: 'core'
}
debugImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.0'

@Test
fun verifyMap() {
     FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(HomeFragment::class.java)

     onView(withId(R.id.map)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

Comment: Why not `androidTestImplementation`?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is (almost) correct - I will just explain why.

So first, you need to change `androidTestImplementation` to `debugImplementation` but only for these 2 dependencies below (not all of them):

```
androidx.fragment:fragment-testing
androidx.test:core
```

And the reason? The root cause is an old bug (since 2020 already) in `FragmentScenario` [reported here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128612536).

Google itself in their own codelabs recommends to not use `androidTestImplementation` for fragment testing dependency, more details here:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-test-doubles#7

Quoting the important part:

```
// Testing code should not be included in the main code.
// Once https://issuetracker.google.com/128612536 is fixed this can be fixed.

implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragmentVersion"
implementation "androidx.test:core:$androidXTestCoreVersion"
```

Except ideally it should be `debugImplementation` and not `implementation`

Answer (score 3):

I also got the same error. But in my case, i forgot to add HiltTestActivity.kt into AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity android:name=".support.view.HiltTestActivity" />
```

And this is my launchFragmentToContainer function.

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragmentToContainer(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    themeResId: Int,
    fragmentFactory: FragmentFactory? = null,
    crossinline action: T.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val mainActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra(THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY, themeResId)
    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(mainActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        fragmentFactory?.let {
            activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = it
        }
        val fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            checkNotNull(T::class.java.classLoader),
            T::class.java.name
        )
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
            .commitNow()
        (fragment as T).action()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with HiltTestActivity.kt, because I insert the AndroidManifest.xml parallel to the activity file.

My fix: Move the AndroidManifest.xml to the java folder.

Comment: Move the AndroidManifest.xml to the "debug folder" not the java folder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I referred the test samples for Espresso and have used the following set of dependencies in app level build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:' + rootProject.androidxCompatVersion
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:' + rootProject.androidxCoreVersion
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:' + rootProject.androidxFragmentVersion

// Ideally this would only be present in test scope (Adding this fixed the issue for me)
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:' + rootProject.androidxFragmentVersion
debugImplementation 'androidx.test:core:' + rootProject.coreVersion

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:' + rootProject.robolectricVersion
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:' + rootProject.coreVersion
testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:' + rootProject.extJUnitVersion
testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:' + rootProject.espressoVersion
testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc4'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:' + rootProject.coreVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:' + rootProject.extJUnitVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:' + rootProject.runnerVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:' + rootProject.espressoVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:' + rootProject.androidxFragmentVersion
androidTestImplementation 'org.robolectric:annotations:' + rootProject.robolectricVersion     }
```

Within you project level build.gradle file

```
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
androidxCoreVersion = "1.1.0-rc02"
androidxCompatVersion = "1.1.0-rc01"
androidxFragmentVersion = "1.1.0-rc01"
coreVersion = "1.3.0-alpha03"
extJUnitVersion = "1.1.2-alpha03"
runnerVersion = "1.3.0-alpha03"
rulesVersion = "1.3.0-alpha03"
espressoVersion = "3.3.0-alpha03"
robolectricVersion = "4.3.1"   }
```

Inside the isolated fragment test class

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
class ExampleFragmentTest{
@Test
fun launchFragmentAndVerifyTheUI(){
   /* This is used to launch the fragment in an isolated environment ( This is essentially an empty activity that
   houses that fragment ) */
   launchFragmentInContainer<ExampleFragment>()
    // Now using Espresso to verify the fragment's UI, i.e textview and verifying that its getting displayed
    onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText("I am a fragment")))
}  }
```